# YouTubePlayerAPI Schedule for Distribution?

Tags: android, youtube-api

Got really excited when I discovered this [Google IO video](http://youtu.be/3WFsx-u-q3Y) recently.  Adding YouTube features to an app easily is very attractive compared to current options (intent, iframe embed)

I was surprised that despite several months since the annoucement, there is virtually nothing out there beyond this video.  The session itself didn't even cover the schedule for release.

Does anyone know where to get a jar, beta or otherwise, to play with?
Does anyone know a schedule for when this might become widely distributed?

I'm hoping someone from the YouTube API Blog and YouTube API Team can address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have anything else to share at this point--the team remains hard at work at getting this launched, but I can't provide a date. We are not distributing beta versions of the Player SDK publicly.

(Also, I'm not positive this is the sort of question that belongs on Stack Overflow--apologies to any moderators if that's the case.)

Comment: Thanks for the update on Player SDK.  I agree with the point about location, but your api blog statement "We encourage all developers who have questions about the YouTube API to start posting on Stack Overflow" led me to believe this was the preference.

Comment: Another update on this would be great. It's been quite some time now.

Comment: Check it out: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/12/no-webview-required-with-native-youtube.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

The API is now available. It works very nice.