# Android YoutubePlayer API

Tags: android, youtube-api

When will the Android Youtube Player API be available to developers. Is there any jar file available on Google Site or when shall it be released publicly as API.

Comment: Ever since IO their has been no talk about it at all, kind of like Android@Home the year before.

Answer (score 2):

It is available now. More information here: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/12/no-webview-required-with-native-youtube.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WFsx-u-q3Y&feature=player_embedded

Till now it is not released, me too waiting for Youtubeplayer API...

This is the alternative solution for android player - http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2011/09/developing-video-player-for-android/?lang=en

If any other than this.. let me know

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [YouTubePlayerAPI Schedule for Distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479365/youtubeplayerapi-schedule-for-distribution).

At that time (Sept 18), they hoped to release 'soon'.  Since then no updates.  I have been watching http://apiblog.youtube.com/ hoping to see something mentioned there.

I'm hoping that we will at least see this available by the next I/O conference in May!

I'm not sure Kumar's link will help, unless it's videoView can handle mp4 that the higher resolution youtube api links provide.